Google Workspace Account throwing error "Service invoked too many times..." after only 20-30 emails
Updating by providing actual code and more details around my issue.
I have a Google Workspace Account that I believe should allow me to send up 1,500 emails per day. I'm running a GAS that calls the Gmail API and it starts sending emails. Why after running this sendTheEmail function 20-30 times would I start getting these error messages:
Error sending email: Service invoked too many times for one day: email.
Stack trace: Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: email.
at sendTheEmail (serverFunctions:612:14)
at GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call.gs:1:8
I have double checked and the GAS is being "Executed as:" using my Google Workspace Account email. I have checked the Google Dashboard and it shows I sent 50 emails.
This is my code, I know it's not pretty.
Do I have to set up the app somehow to ensure it is using the proper account/quota?
Is there a way I can determine exactly why this quota is being reached? Could it be something else that is being triggered? If so, how can I capture and determine exactly what is?
Am I missing something on how the quota is calculated?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
**Note: I even changed the code to use MailApp to send the emails, so I could then see the getRemainingDailyQuota. I realize this is probably not exact due to caching, etc. but the numbers I getting returned even at the start of the day are around 10 or 12. I never see 1,500.
function sendTheEmail(data, eEmailTemplateLink, eMaskID, eCreateLink, eFrom, eReplyTo, eCC, eSubject, eIfSubmissionLink, eTrackEXE, eShop) {
 
  try {
    responses = JSON.stringify(data);
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(responses);

    // Access individual elements
    var eOrderNo = jsonObject.ORDERNO || jsonObject.OrderNo;   
    var eEmail = jsonObject.email;
    var eFirst = jsonObject.first; 
    var eLast = jsonObject.last; 
    var eGrader = jsonObject.grader;
    var eServiceLevel = jsonObject.service_level;
    var eCards = jsonObject.cards;
    var eOrderDate = jsonObject.order_date; 
    var eSubmission = jsonObject.submission;
    var ePaymentType = jsonObject.payment;
    var ePhone = jsonObject.phone;
    var eAddress1 = jsonObject.address1;
    var eAddress2 = jsonObject.address2;
    var eCity = jsonObject.city;
    var eState = jsonObject.state;
    var eZip = jsonObject.zip;
    var eExam = jsonObject.exam ? "Yes" : "No";   
    var eComments = jsonObject.comments;
    var eCert_Links = jsonObject.comments;
    var eImage1 = jsonObject.image1;
    var eImage2 = jsonObject.image2;
    var eImage3 = jsonObject.image3;
    var eImage4 = jsonObject.image4;
    var eImage5 = jsonObject.image5;
    var eImage6 = jsonObject.image6;
    

    if (eMaskID && eSubmission !== "" && eSubmission !== undefined) {
      var eSubmission = "ST"+ encryptNumber(eSubmission, 3);     
      Logger.log("encrypted SubmissionID" + eSubmission);
    }


    if (eSubmission !== "" && eSubmission !== undefined && eGrader === "XYZ" && eCreateLink) {
      var eSubmissionLink = eTrackEXE + "?shop=" + eShop + "&sub=" + eSubmission;
      eSubmission = '<a href="' + eSubmissionLink + '">' + eSubmission + '</a>';
    }


    // if eSubject has {{ORDER_NUMBER}} replace it with eOrderNo
    eSubject = eSubject.replace(/{{ORDER_NUMBER}}/g, eOrderNo);

    // read in the email template doc as a string.
    var docId = DocumentApp.openByUrl(eEmailTemplateLink).getId();
    var eBody = docToHtml(docId);


    if (eSubmission !== "" && eSubmission !== undefined && eGrader === "XYZ" && eCreateLink) {
      eBody = eBody.replace(/{{IF_SUBMISSION_LINK}}/g, eIfSubmissionLink);
    } else {
      eBody = eBody.replace (/{{IF_SUBMISSION_LINK}}/g, "");
    }

    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{ORDER_NUMBER}}/g, eOrderNo);
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{EMAIL}}/g, eEmail !== undefined ? eEmail : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{ORDER_DATE}}/g, eOrderDate !== undefined ? eOrderDate : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{COMPANY}}/g, eGrader !== undefined ? eGrader : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{SERVICE_LEVEL}}/g, eServiceLevel !== undefined ? eServiceLevel : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{CARDS}}/g, eCards !== undefined ? eCards : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{SUBMISSION_ID}}/g, eSubmission !== undefined ? eSubmission : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{PAYMENT_TYPE}}/g, ePaymentType !== undefined ? ePaymentType : "");    
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{FIRST}}/g, eFirst !== undefined ? eFirst : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{LAST}}/g, eLast !== undefined ? eLast : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{ADDRESS1}}/g, eAddress1 !== undefined ? eAddress1 : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{ADDRESS2}}/g, eAddress2 !== undefined ? eAddress2 : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{CITY}}/g, eCity !== undefined ? eCity : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{STATE}}/g, eState !== undefined ? eState : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{ZIP}}/g, eZip !== undefined ? eZip : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{PHONE}}/g, ePhone !== undefined ? ePhone : "");
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{CARD_EXAM}}/g, eExam !== undefined ? eExam : "");  
    //Logger.log("eComments:", eComments);  
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{COMMENTS}}/g, eComments !== undefined ? eComments : ""); 

    if (eCert_Links !== undefined) {
      eCert_Links = eCert_Links.replace(/~/g, '<br>').replace(/(<br>)(\d+)/g, '$1<a href="https://example.com/cert/$2">$2</a>');
    }
    eBody = eBody.replace(/{{CERT_LINKS}}/g, eCert_Links !== undefined ? eCert_Links : "");

      
    // Fetch image blobs from Google Drive only if there's an image link
    var image1Blob = eImage1 ? getImageBlobFromDrive(eImage1, "newName1") : null;    
    var image2Blob = eImage2 ? getImageBlobFromDrive(eImage2) : null;
    var image3Blob = eImage3 ? getImageBlobFromDrive(eImage3) : null;
    var image4Blob = eImage4 ? getImageBlobFromDrive(eImage4) : null;
    var image5Blob = eImage5 ? getImageBlobFromDrive(eImage5) : null;
    var image6Blob = eImage6 ? getImageBlobFromDrive(eImage6) : null;
    
     // rename blobs, otherwise they are all named uc.jpg
    var counter = 1;
    var filePrefix = eShop + "_" + eOrderNo + "_";

    // Assuming image1Blob, image2Blob, image3Blob, and image4Blob are Blob objects
    var blobs = [image1Blob, image2Blob, image3Blob, image4Blob, image5Blob, image6Blob];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < blobs.length; i++) {
        var currentBlob = blobs[i];

        // Check if the current blob is not null
        if (currentBlob !== null) {
            var newFilename = filePrefix + counter;
            currentBlob.setName(newFilename);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    // Attach images only if there's a corresponding blob
    var attachments = [image1Blob, image2Blob, image3Blob, image4Blob, image5Blob, image6Blob].filter(blob => blob !== null);

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: eEmail,
      replyTo: eReplyTo,
      cc: eCC,
      subject: eSubject,
      htmlBody: eBody,
      attachments: attachments
    });

    // Logging to monitor email limits
    Logger.log("Email sent successfully");
    var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
    Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);    
   
//  GmailApp.sendEmail(eEmail, eSubject, '', {
//    htmlBody: eBody,
//    from: "XYTrack    " + "<" + eFrom + ">",
//    replyTo: eReplyTo,
//    cc: eCC,
//    attachments: attachments   
//  });

    status = 'sent';
    return status;
 } catch (error) {
    // If there's an error in sending the email, log the error and return false
    Logger.log("Error sending email:", error.message);
    Logger.log("Stack trace:", error.stack);
    return 'error';
 }
}


Try slowing the loop down.  They don't wait for you to exceed a daily total they measure the send rate instead.
